# (C++) Getting the following compilation error: cannot convert 'DoubleNode<int>' to 'DoubleNode<int>*' in initialization

Tags: c++, pointers, error-handling, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile a Doubly Linked List program and the following error occurs at the insert function.

```
DoublyLinkedList.cpp:23:26: error: cannot convert 'DoubleNode<int>' to 'DoubleNode<int>*' in initialization
   23 |    DoubleNode<ItemType>* prevPtr = getAtPos(position - 1);
      |                          ^~~~~~~
      |                          |
      |                          DoubleNode<int>
```

Relevant lines of code:

```
DoubleNode<ItemType>* newNodePtr = new DoubleNode<ItemType>(item);
if (position == 1){
    // insert new double node at the begining of the chain
    newNodePtr->setNext(headPtr);
    headPtr = newNodePtr;
}
else{
    // find node that will be before new node
    DoubleNode<ItemType>* prevPtr = getAtPos(position - 1);
    newNodePtr->setNext(prevPtr->getNext());
    prevPtr->getNext()->setPrev(newNodePtr);
    newNodePtr->setPrev(prevPtr);
    prevPtr->setNext(newNodePtr);
```

getAtPost function:

```
template<class ItemType>
DoubleNode<ItemType> DoublyLinkedList<ItemType>::getAtPos(const int& position) const
{
    // count from begining of chain
    DoubleNode<ItemType>* curPtr = headPtr;
    for (int i = 1; i < position; i++){
        curPtr = curPtr->getNext();
    }
    return *curPtr;
}  // end getAtPos
```

Comment: What does the `getAtPos` function return ?

Comment: Your getAtPos() probably returns DoubleNode<int> and not DoubleNode<int>*. Maybe you can try DoubleNode<ItemType>* prevPtr = &(getAtPos(position -1);

Comment: I have tried DoubleNode<ItemType>* prevPtr = &(getAtPos(position -1)); That returns this error: DoublyLinkedList.cpp:23:36: error: taking address of rvalue [-fpermissive

Comment: If it returns a DoubleNode<ItemType> why don't you change the type to that, or have it return a DoubleNode<ItemType>*

Comment: For the purpose of what I want to do, getAtPos must return DoubleNode<ItemType>

Comment: Then change to DoubleNode<ItemType> prevPtr. For the purpose you are showing it clearly needs to be a pointer. It needs to return curPtr not *curPtr.

Comment: @chris_b "*For the purpose of what I want to do, getAtPos must return DoubleNode<ItemType>*" - it makes no sense to return a *copy* of a node from the list, rather than return a pointer to the original node. You are also not handling the possibility of the `position` parameter specifying an index that is out of bounds of the list.

Comment: Your implementation of this structure is very weird. I also suggest not using a position variable to keep track of how many stuff you have in the chain/list. Each node has a previous/next pointer use those and loops to determine how far to traverse

Comment: Upon further inspection my professor most likely made a typo in the assignment and I should be returning a pointer rather than a copy of a node.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getAtPos()` method is returning a *copy* of a `DoubleNode<ItemType>` object from the list, rather than returning a *pointer* to the original object, which is what the caller is actually expecting.

You are also not handling the possibility of the `position` parameter specifying an index that is out of bounds of the list.

Try this instead:

```cpp
template<class ItemType>
DoubleNode<ItemType>* DoublyLinkedList<ItemType>::getAtPos(int position) const
{
    DoubleNode<ItemType>* curPtr = nullptr;

    if (position >= 0) {
        curPtr = headPtr;
        while ((curPtr) && (position > 0)) {
            curPtr = curPtr->getNext();
            --position;
        }
    }

    if (!curPtr)
        return nullptr; // or throw an exception...

    return curPtr;
}
```